# How to copy an html element's markup and style entirely

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

Is there a tool I can use (preferably in chrome) to copy the entire html and relevant css code for an element and it's child elements?

Comment: I don't know about Chrome but in Firefox, in the inspect element tab, you can right-click a HTML element to copy its entire interior and all its child elements. Plus you can access the entire CSS stylesheet.

Comment: This, works for copying the HTML code but not CSS.

Comment: please upvote me and mark me as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the element and then inspect, you can copy the style and the html like this to copy the element's HTML:

[image]

Also to copy its style:

[image]